# How to Process SQL Query data in Php Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, phpmyadmin, data-processing

NOTE:it's a specific issue, need answer for that.

This is my database table from where i want to fetch data. 
[image: Database Table]

**my DB Query**

```
select std.reg_id, std.name as student_name, r.marks as obtain_marks, q.ques_marks as total_marks,  cat.name as category_name, q.cat_id, course.name as course_name 
FROM tbl_result as r JOIN tbl_question as q on q.id = r.ques_id 
JOIN tbl_category as cat on cat.id = q.cat_id
JOIN tbl_batch_assigned_courses as assign on assign.id = r.course_offered_id 
JOIN tbl_courses as course on course.id = assign.course_id 
JOIN tbl_student as std on std.id = r.student_id 
WHERE r.student_id = 168 AND r.course_offered_id = 46
```

You see? There are many categories and each category has **Obtain and total marks**.

now what I want is to fetch the data from this table **(already did)** and display it on the view **(already did)**.

But along with that I want to show that total obtain marks and and total marks of each category, and also sum of both.

**For example:**

Communication Skills has total obtain marks of 15 marks
and it's total marks are 25.

(total obtain / total question marks) * 100 ~= [some value] for Category 1.

but i want the above expression for all categories (could be any number).

Php should do it automatically, just by passing, student, and course id.

**My Controller Code:**

```
public function show_single_student_report(){
            $go = $this->input->post("submit_go");
            if(isset($go)) {
                $program_id = $this->input->post('program_id');
                $batch_id = $this->input->post('batch_id');
                $course_id = $this->input->post('course_id');
                $student_id = $this->input->post('student_id');

                $data['results'] = $this->csv_model->get_single_student_result($student_id, $course_id);

                $this->load->view('show_single_student_report', $data);
            }
            else{
                redirect("main/check_result");
            }


        }
```

the view code is :

```
$this->load->view('show_single_student_report', $data);
```

this

```
<?php foreach ($results as $std):  ?>
<div class="row">

         <?php $obtain += $std->obtain_marks; ?>
         Name : <?= $std->student_name;?> <br>
         obtain marks: <?= $std->obtain_marks; ?> <br>
         total_marks: <?= $std->total_marks;?> <br>
         category: <?= $std->category_name; ?><br>
         course: <?= $std->course_name; ?><br>
         category_id: <?= $std->cat_id;?> <br>
         </div>
         <div style="height: 50px;"></div>

         <?php endforeach;?>
```

Basically I don't know how to iterate the MYSQL Query via PHP.

Comment: what exactly in your foreach do you want to change? you want to perform this calc: `(total obtain / total question marks) * 100` foreach row? it would be helpful if you could render and example table of what you want to accomplish

Comment: I added the table screenshot but It's showing,
http://nimb.ws/3g4Tb2 link of table screenshot.

Comment: for each Category. you can check the table in the image. 
I want to iterate through all the categories. and get the total obtain and total marks of the each category.

Comment: so basically you just want to have no repeating categories. so for example, you don't see it as represented in your image. instead you see only one time `Tools and tech  skills` and then you see obtained marks 8 and total marks 10?

Comment: Ummm, i guess yes
basically I want to have total of obtain and total questions marks for each category, one by one. 

check this table. http://nimb.ws/Cw3m8A
this is for one category. 
i want to iterate this from codeigniter so i can get the same table for all categories and display the total of marks

Comment: so you want it to look **exactly** like that table (just assuming more than that particular category) and where do you want to display the category totals then? it would really help me to provide you a solution if you made a mock table (not in sql) using the real data and where you plan on placing the totals .etc.. just have to do a few rows so i can get the idea. probably only takes a few minutes to do.

Comment: I want to view the obtain and total in view file, 

example $this->load->view('anyfile',$data);
okay I'll send you the ss of Table.

Answer (score 1):

You want to modify your query to aggregate the marks by category.

Try running:

```
SELECT 
    q.cat_id,
    SUM(r.marks) AS obtain_marks,
    SUM(q.ques_marks) AS total_marks,
FROM tbl_result as r 
JOIN tbl_question as q on q.id = r.ques_id 
GROUP BY q.cat_id
```

This should give you an idea how SUM() and GROUP BY works together.
Then, just join it up with your other data:

```
SELECT 
std.reg_id, 
std.name as student_name
FROM tbl_student as std
JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    q.cat_id,
    r.student_id,
    SUM(r.marks) AS obtain_marks,
    SUM(q.ques_marks) AS total_marks,
    FROM tbl_result as r 
    JOIN tbl_question as q on q.id = r.ques_id 
    WHERE r.student_id = std.id
    GROUP BY q.cat_id
) tbl1
ON tbl1.student_id = std.id
```